# Yii2 - Command Controller not working getalias webroot

Tags: php, yii, yii2, command

When I run the command controller via terminal, the
`Yii::getAlias('@webroot')` does not work =/

Command ( QueuePushNotificationController.php ) :

```
<?php
     namespace app\commands;

     use Yii;
     use yii\console\Controller;

     class QueuePushNotificationController extends Controller
     {
         public function actionIndex()
         {
             echo Yii::getAlias('@webroot');
         }
     }
```

execute via terminal:

```
./yii queue-push-notification
```

return:

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Invalid path alias: @webroot'
```

Does not work out of the application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

in yii2 command undefind (webroot or web) alias, web index.php yii\web\Application.php defind method

```
 protected function bootstrap()
 {
      $request = $this->getRequest();
      Yii::setAlias('@webroot', dirname($request->getScriptFile()));
      Yii::setAlias('@web', $request->getBaseUrl());

      parent::bootstrap();
 }
```

but,you can see yii\console\Application no bootstrap() method.
You can solve this problem well,

```
 public function init()
 {
        Yii::setAlias('@webroot', Specific path );
        Yii::setAlias('@web', Specific path);
        parent::init(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ishengge for your answer, here what I have done than

```
public function init()
{
    Yii::setAlias('@webroot', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'));
    parent::init(); 
}
```